# Backbone.js & localstorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

Trying to get my head around backbone.js.  This example is using [Backbone Boilerplate](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate) and [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) and I'm coming up against a confusing problem;  When quizes.create(...) is called I get this error:

> backbone.js:570 - Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
>
> model = new this.model(attrs, {collection: this});

Quiz module code:

```
(function(Quiz) {
Quiz.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({ /* ... */ });

Quiz.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Quiz,
    localStorage: new Store("quizes")
});
quizes = new Quiz.Collection;

Quiz.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({ /* ... */ });

Quiz.Views.Question = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "app/templates/quiz.html",

    events: {
        'click #save': 'saveForm'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.counter = 0;
    },

    render: function(done) {
        var view = this;
        namespace.fetchTemplate(this.template, function(tmpl) {
            view.el.innerHTML = tmpl();
            done(view.el);
        });
    },
    saveForm: function(data){
        if (this.counter <= 0) {
            $('#saved ul').html('');
        }
        this.counter++;
        var titleField = $('#title').val();
        console.log(quizes);
        quizes.create({title: titleField});

    }

});

})(namespace.module("quiz"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Collection, you're naming `model` as your `Quiz` object, not the actual `Quiz.Model`. So, when you call `new this.model()`, you're actually calling `Quiz()` - which is an object, not a function. You need to change the code to:

```
Quiz.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Quiz.Model, // Change this to the actual model instance
  localStorage: new Store("quizes")
});
```